# java.lang.NullPointerException error in Java program to add 2 objects

Tags: java

I have some trouble handling memory in Java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class P4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Matrix x=new Matrix(2,4);
        Matrix y=new Matrix(2,4);
        Matrix a=new Matrix(2,4);
        Matrix b=new Matrix(2,4);
        Matrix c=new Matrix(2,4);
        x=a.input();
        y=b.input();
        c=x.add(y);
        c.display();
    }
}
class Matrix{
    private int x,y;
    double m[][];
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    Matrix(int a1,int b1){
        x=a1;
        y=b1;
    }
    public Matrix input() {
        double m[][]=new double[x][y];
        System.out.println("Enter "+x*y+" elements : ");
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<y;j++){
                m[i][j]=in.nextDouble();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("You Entered : ");
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<y;j++){
                System.out.printf("%f\t",m[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        return this;
    }
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Elements in the Matrix are : ");
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<y;j++){
                System.out.printf("%f\t",m[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public Matrix add(Matrix n) {
        Matrix temp=new Matrix(n.x,n.y);
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<y;j++){
                temp.m[i][j]=m[i][j]+n.m[i][j];
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
    public Matrix sub(Matrix n) {
        Matrix temp=new Matrix(n.x,n.y);
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<y;j++){
                temp.m[i][j]=m[i][j]-n.m[i][j];
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

In the above code I'm unable to to hold x and y in memory (tried to keep them in reference by using a dummy a and b), as a result  I'm unable to call add() which cause the error.

BTW, my output:

```
Enter 8 elements : 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
You Entered : 
1.000000    2.000000    3.000000    4.000000    
5.000000    6.000000    7.000000    8.000000    
Enter 8 elements : 
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
You Entered : 
Exception in thread "main" 8.000000 7.000000    6.000000    5.000000    
4.000000    3.000000    2.000000    1.000000    
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Matrix.add(P4.java:53)
    at P4.main(P4.java:11)
```

Comment: line 11:         c=x.add(y);
line 53:         temp.m[i][j]=m[i][j]+n.m[i][j];

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 1):

In the method `input()`, you are declaring:

```
double m[][]=new double[x][y];
```

This hides the instance variable `m`, which is left with its default value of `null`. Later, when you later try to access the elements of `m`, you are getting the NPE. Just change that line to:

```
m[][]=new double[x][y];
```

Also, in your `add` and `sub` methods, you are trying to access `temp.m` without initializing it. That would also generate an NPE and should be changed.

The best thing, I think, would be to change your constructor:

```
Matrix(int a1,int b1){
    x=a1;
    y=b1;
    m = new int[a1][b1];
}
```

and eliminate the initialization in `input()`. There's no reason to defer the initialization of `m`.

Comment: +1. However, I would argue (pedantically) that `m` is not actually a class variable, but an instance variable. An instance variable becomes a class variable in Java when marked `static`.

Comment: @CraigOtis - Right. Updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

in the input()-method for matrix, you declare a new array, try this instead:

```
 public Matrix input() {
 //m = new double[x][y]; // do not instantiate a new m[][] here
```

And in the constructor, add the instatiation

```
Matrix(int a1, int b1) {
    x = a1;
    y = b1;
    m = new double[a1][b1];
}
```